# Get "corners" of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array in the shape [64,64], and I want to split the array into four, each containing a quadrant of the original.

On a smaller scale, (for example) I have a [4,4] array here:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
                [5,6,7,8],
                [9,8,7,6],
                [5,4,3,2]])
```

And I want to select these values as their own arrays:

[image]

Meaning I would end with:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,5,6],
                [3,4,7,8],
                [9,8,5,4],
                [7,6,3,2]])
```

Apologizes for anything I may have missed. I am new to python

Comment: Simply reshape the output you would get using the linked answer back to the original/desired shape.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find the other answer as the title was a bit cryptic.